# Difference between duration and relative duration in procmon

Tags: windows, procmon

In the following image, as we can see there are 2 time which are duration and relative duration. I am not able to find out the basic difference between them. 
Why is duration of process create is 0.000000? 
Can i know the how much time it took to start the process in procmon or other software.  [screenshot of procmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxSVk.png) [process creation duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bwvL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find those information within the procmon help file:

- **Relative Time**: The time of the operation relative to Process Monitor's start time or the last time that the Process Monitor display was cleared.
- **Duration**: The duration of an operation that has completed.

Comment: so why process creation duration is 0.0000 and is relative time a correct measure to find out the time it took to start an application.

Comment: The duration is never just 0.0000000, at least not in your screenshot. Since every operation is listed, you have to add the values for the same PID together to get what you want.

Comment: I have added the new screenshot of procmon of only process creation.  I have open excel and powerpoint but still their duration is 0.000000